# Navigation bar stops working after applying a layer mask

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios5, core-graphics, uibezierpath, cashapelayer

I used a CAShapeLayer to create a mask, which I gave round corners at the top left/right then applied it to my `navigationController`'s `navigationBar`.

It works like a charm, but I've now noticed I can't use buttons on the navigation bar!

Here's the code I use (in `viewDidLoad`):

```
UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.navigationController.navigationBar.bounds
                                               byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerTopLeft | UIRectCornerTopRight
                                                     cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(6.0, 6.0)];

CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
maskLayer.frame = self.navigationController.navigationBar.bounds;
maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;

self.navigationController.navigationBar.layer.mask = maskLayer;
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to set the buttons programmatically after setting the layer mask.

Comment: What do you mean by that? Set them how?